# Fallback languages in Firefox

Tags: firefox, fonts, language

I'm something of an amateur linguist and as a result have a tendency to read articles in ... *peculiar* languages. Like Akkadian cuneiform.

Usually, this requires either the page itself to recognize that this is a problem and specify a special font for me to use, or for me to configure the language-appropriate font as a fallback. Unfortunately that means that I can only read one "peculiar" language at a time without reconfiguring Firefox.

Is there there some way to tell Firefox "go look through this folder for fonts that implement this block", instead of specifying a particular font?

Comment: What do you mean by "*reconfiguring* Firefox? I cannot follow what you have tried to do. You should give a specific example and list all steps you have tried so far. With screenshots if possible.

Comment: Tools->Options->Content->Fonts&Colors->Advanced->Other Writing Systems: set to whatever I need that day.